# Enviroment variables ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, apt

Does the enviroment variables need to be set manually in the **ubuntu** os? because i followed some instructions in different sites to install specific software using **apt** as package installer and all of the sites instuctions don't add instructions for adding the enviroment variables, so are the enviroment variables set automatically??

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the installed software. Generally the installed programs through `apt` doesn't require the modification of the environment variable. Others way (compiled, binary ...) programs require to set its variables correctly.

Ubuntu help: [Environment Variables](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EnvironmentVariables)